# Macro in Outlook to delete duplicate emails-

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, outlook

```
Public Sub RemDups()

Dim t As Items, _
    i As Integer, _
    arr As Collection, _
    f As Folder, _
    parent As Folder, _
    target As Folder, _
    miLast As MailItem, _
    mi As MailItem

Set parent = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
Set target = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder


For Each f In parent.Folders
    Set t = f.Items
    t.Sort "[Subject]"
    i = 1
    Set miLast = t(i)
    Set arr = New Collection
    While i < t.Count
        i = i + 1
        If TypeName(t(i)) = "MailItem" Then
            Set mi = t(i)
            If miLast.Subject = mi.Subject And miLast.Body = mi.Body _
            And miLast.ReceivedTime = mi.ReceivedTime Then
                arr.Add mi
            Else
                Set miLast = mi
            End If
        End If
    Wend
    For Each mi In arr
        mi.Move target
    Next mi
Next f

End Sub
```

**Set miLast = t(i) gives "Run-time error'440' Array index out of bounds**
Please help

Comment: What's the value of `f.Items.Count` when you get that error ?

Comment: When I complie the code, all I get is "Runtime error". It does not give any count

Comment: Use the **t.Item(i)** method to get the item by the index in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version founded in the web ([Blog ExcelandAccess](https://excelandaccess.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/delete-duplicate-emails-via-ms-excel-vba/#comment-1493))

This code let pick a folder to search and delete duplicate items.

```
Option Explicit

'Set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime from Tools, References.

Sub DeleteDuplicateEmailsInSelectedFolder()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim Message As String
Dim Items As Object
Dim AppOL As Object
Dim NS As Object
Dim Folder As Object

Set Items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Initialize and instance of Outlook
Set AppOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Get the MAPI Name Space
Set NS = AppOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Allow the user to select a folder in Outlook
Set Folder = NS.PickFolder

'Get the count of the number of emails in the folder
n = Folder.Items.Count

'Check each email starting from the last and working backwards to 1
'Loop backwards to ensure that the deleting of the emails does not interfere with subsequent items in the loop
For i = n To 1 Step -1

    On Error Resume Next
    'Load the matching criteria to a variable
    'This is setup to use the Sunject and Body, additional criteria could be added if desired
    Message = Folder.Items(i).Subject & "|" & Folder.Items(i).Body

        'Check a dictionary variable for a match
        If Items.Exists(Message) = True Then
        'If the item has previously been added then delete this duplicate
        Folder.Items(i).Delete
    Else
        'In the item has not been added then add it now so subsequent matches will be deleted
        Items.Add Message, True
End If

Next i

ExitSub:

'Release the object variables from memory
Set Folder = Nothing
Set NS = Nothing
Set AppOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

A better version is to find duplicate e-mails in other folder in recursive mode.