# Delete duplicate emails from Outlook365 Using Outlook 2016 VBA

Tags: outlook, office365

There was a bad recovery process when E-mails were recovered from different `PSTs` and thus duplicating some emails.

I've tried the cleanup utility and that doesn't find them.

I've tried the method that involves sorting by modified that, but don't trust it.

I've tried some VBA code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669174/remove-duplicate-outlook-items-from-a-folder), and [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/quickly-remove-duplicate-outlook-items-folder-via-vba/) but I get some errors on the type of item it tries to view. Since some properties change on the item and get a reference error.

With the VBA codes that I tried thus far, I've noticed that the e-mail count is way lower than what I really have.

I'm looking for a free alternative, since there are a couple of software for purchase that claim to do the same.

Comment: While this isn't VBA I would suggest https://eightwone.com/2013/06/21/removing-duplicate-items-from-a-mailbox/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166631/4539709

Comment: @0m3r That was for RS, but I changed the command to olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox), still didn't get the correct count.

Comment: share/post your current code